# Restrict a Wordpress Template to show only one category

Tags: wordpress, categories, restrict

I tried everything found in the web, but i'm getting errors or that's not what I am searching for...

I have to make a PAGE in wordpress, to show ONLY the posts of the category with a certain ID ( in my case id=8 )
i tryed to edit the loop-xxxx.php .. the template file... everything but I get always a problem
navigation system doesn't work. I mean... getting back to older posts won't work cause the output shows the last posts instead of older one.

The code I'm using in the loop or in the template file is:

```
<?php
query_posts('cat=8');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

i tried inserting it before the

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

in loop.php

or before the call of loop inside the index.php

please help me :\

Answer (score 0):

**One solution is to use a custom WP_Query.** In the custom page's TEMPLATE file, where `ID` is the id of the targeted category:

```
<?php $tmp_query = new WP_Query('cat=ID');
    while ( $tmp_query->have_posts() ) : $tmp_query->the_post();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't fix my problem :\ when surfing to previous page ecc... ( &paged=2 ) i can't see the other posts. The output is the same of the main page

ex.
cat. 1
post 1 to 8
posts in first page = 4

those 4 posts remain the same on the other pages

Comment: @LorenzoPimps You comment is not very clear to me. Is pagination broken on your custom page?

Comment: my english really sux at this time :D
worked all the day... anyway... the code to restrict category works of course. The only problem is that pagination DON'T ! Going back to "other posts" ( the &paged=2 for example ) returns back the same items of the main page :(
the code is the original one of twentiet theme in wp

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=8'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<optional> You can write here: "You are in category X". </optional>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Good luck.